# How can I use only PDF files in View of AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

I use Emacs on Mac, and I use AUCTeX to edit TeX files. I use `auto-complete-auctex`, too.

If I use <kbd>C-c C-v</kbd> just after opening a TeX file, a PDF file opens.However, if I use <kbd>C-c C-v</kbd> after compiling, a DVI file opens. I want to use only PDF files to preview. How can I achieve this?

Here are my settings:

```
;; Automatic Parsing of TeX files.
(setq TeX-parse-self t)

;; latexmk
(auctex-latexmk-setup)

;; auto-complete
(require 'auto-complete-auctex)

(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn
     (setq TeX-command-default "LatexMk")
     (setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Skim" "/usr/bin/open -a Skim.app %o")))
     (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-dvi "Skim")
                                        (output-pdf "Skim")))
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c j") 'latex-math-preview-insert-symbol)))
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but I found a solution by myself.
`     (setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Skim" "/usr/bin/open -a Skim.app %o")
                                   ("Skim-dvi" "f=%o; open -a Skim.app \"${f%.dvi}.pdf\"")))
     (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-dvi "Skim-dvi")
                                        (output-pdf "Skim")))`

Comment: By using either `(TeX-global-PDF-mode t)` or `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (setq TeX-PDF-mode t)))`, there would be no need to trick AUCTeX into thinking it is opening up a `*.dvi` file (when in reality it is opening up a `*.pdf` file).  Setting the variable `TeX-PDF-mode` to `t` permits AUCTeX to use `output-pdf`.